# TeXStudio: redefined newcommand variant has bad error highlighting

Tags: math-mode, macros, texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I would like to use the following command in my LaTeX code

```
\newcommand{\newsym}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}
```

so that I can easily define new symbols that I often use in my equations, such as:

```
\newsym{\kTq}{\frac{k_BT}{q}}.
```

The intent being to reduce the amount of typing necessary to define new symbols and to enhance readability of the code.

The problem now is twofold:

- TeXstudio dosn't realize my `\newsym` defines a new command and complains that the first argument (`\kTq`) is an uncrecognized command.
- It also doesn't realize the second argument is eventually enclosed in an `\ensuremath` environment and complains *math command outside math environment*

As a result I have my `\newsym` definitions cluttered with bad-syntax highlighting, impeding the readability, which was the <del>entire</del> half of the purpose of defining `\newsum` in the first place.

Can I solve this dilemma by somehow adjusting the way TeXstudio does the error highlighting in this particular case? I don't wan't to disable the highlighting altogether; they are otherwise useful.

Or is there a smarter alternative to my definition of `\newsym` that avoids this problem?

Comment: you can ignore that, as this stems from autocompletion in TXS, or you can write a custom `.cwl` for TXS to recognize your custom commands.

Comment: why do you need `\ensuremath` here at all?  do you use `\kTq` outside of math mode?

Comment: Thanks naphaneal. the custom .cwl might be the solution I'm looking for. Could you elaborate on how to do that in a answer to the question I would then accept that answer as the solution if it works.

Comment: David, without the `\ensuremath`, as is also the case when I use `\newsym`, teXstudio will highlight the math-mode commands in the new symbol's definition. It's true that the new symbol still works nonetheless and you are right that I don't use the new symbol outside math-mode but that wasn't the point.

Comment: it was one of your two bulletpoints, but without `\ensuremath` the new command is just the same as `\newcommand` so you could use that and presumably your editor will be happy without any more work needed.

Answer (score 2):

How to create a custom `.cwl`-file for TXS:

1. Open any ASCII-Text editor of your choice, e.g. `vi`, `Notepad++`. Alternatively: use TXS.
2. Create and save a new text file with the file extension `.cwl`. If created for a package, the `.cwl`-file needs to be named in compliance to the package name.
3. Add all commands you created as follows:

   `#<author> <date>
   \<command>{<arguments>}
   \begin{<environmentname>}
   \end{<environmentname>}`
4. Save and copy or move your `.cwl`-file to the settings directory of TXS. For Windows 7 it is in `%AppData%\texstudio\completion\user`.
5. Restart TXS, if necessary and goto `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Completion`. Check box of your `.cwl`-file.

`#` indicates comment line unless used within 
classification or with keywords. For more information refer to [TXS manual section 4.13](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) or [TXS FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/) .

## Example:

`example.cwl`

`#naphaneal/2016-07-01
\begin{my-code}
\end{my-code}`

Comment: In particular, for the above case add `\newsym{cmd}{def}#d`.